# Why does Drupal display node titles at the page level instead of the node level?

Tags: theming, nodes

I'm doing some work with ['Extra Fields'](http://www.treehouseagency.com/learn/view-modes/extra-fields) and keep tripping up on the fact that Drupal tends to display the title of a node at the page level when viewing the full node page. It seems to be that it makes more sense to always display the title at the node level. Is there a reason I'm not seeing that makes it better to display it at the page level instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every page is a node. It's really as simple as that; if node pages' titles were displayed on the node level but other pages' titles were displayed at the page level it makes things inconsistent and more difficult to maintain, document, predict, etc.